# How to test style css custom var in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am creating a test in VUEJS, and I want to get the style.
My component is used like this:

:style="background-color: var(--color)"

I'm using the following methods:

1. wrapper.find('.avatar').attributes().style
2. wrapper.find('.avatar').element.style.getPropertyValue('background-color')

How do I mock the var(--color) custom variable in my tests?

Answer (score 2):

To test this, we'd need a way to specify CSS variables in a parent element that propagates the variable to its children. Unfortunately, Jest uses JSDOM, which does not fully support CSS variables. It has a [partial implementation](https://github.com/jsdom/cssstyle/pull/111), which only applies CSS variables to a single element, and does not cascade it to child elements.

However, if JSDOM ever adds support for CSS variables, the test would look something like this:

1. Create an HTML element (e.g., named "`testEl`"), where we could set a CSS property.
2. Set the `--color` property on the element with [`testEl.style.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
3. Use Vue Test Utils's [`attachTo` mounting option](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto) to mount the test component onto the  element created above.
4. Use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on the wrapper element to get the styles computed from CSS variables, and [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to get the computed value of `background-color`, which should equal the value set in step 2 (i.e., `blue`).

*Example (theoretical):*

```js
describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('receives --color', async () => {
    const testDiv = document.createElement('div')
    testDiv.style.setProperty('--color', 'blue')

    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      attachTo: testDiv
    })

    // ⛔️this will fail because JSDOM doesn't fully support CSS variables
    expect(getComputedStyle(wrapper.element).getPropertyValue('background-color')).toBe('blue')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, you just resolved my 3h workaround search adventure